# too many files on a network mount causes mount to take a lot of time

Tags: sshfs

If I try to mount using

```
sshfs -o allow_other,default_permissions user@server:/dir-with-lots-of-subprojects ~/projects
```

then it's taking an unacceptably long time (> 10 seconds, and perhaps even more, so I killed it because my patience didn't allow it)

However, if I use

```
sshfs -o allow_other,default_permissions user@server:/dir-with-lots-of-subprojects/specific-project ~/specific-project
```

Then everything happens fast.

I'm assuming every file has to be scanned and indexed on a mount and that's why the previous operation is taking so long. Can this be avoided? Are there other options (like NFS) which are immune to this?

Comment: Reorganize your `/dir-with-lots-of-projects` directory. Use subdirectories, e.g. `/dir-with-lots-of-projects/projects-beginning-with-A`, `/dir-with-lots-of-projects/projects-beginning-with-B`, etc.

Comment: @waltinator that's an ugly, time-intensive workaround. I suspect that lazy loading of files should be possible, i.e. when I open a directory then files immediately within that directory are indexed but nothing else.

Comment: This seems to happen when a media device is connected to the computer, e.g. a smartphone's "internal memory"